# how to Get sharePoint edit document properties in spfx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-framework

how to edit properties for document in sharepoint SPFX? inside a webpart. Is it possible to do something like in the image I added?

[image]

Comment: Thank you R. Sperre.
I was wondering if it was possible to get url of the document properties panel. the one we have in a document Lib. so that i can hit a button in my home page a modify a specific document properties in panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [PnPjs](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs) this is quite easy:

```
let filePath = this.context.pageContext.site.serverRelativeUrl + '/Documents/Test.docx';

let updateProperties = { 
    Title: 'Updated title',
    AnotherColumn: 'Another value'
};

sp.web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(filePath).getItem().then((listItem:Item) => {
    listItem.update(updateProperties);
});
```

Comment: Thank you R. Sperre.

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to get url of the document properties panel. the one we have in a document Lib. so that i can hit a button in my home page a modify a specific document properties in panel.

Comment: I think the closest you can get to that is by embedding the classic EditForm.aspx in a frame and supplying the item ID :
"<Library>/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=3&IsDlg=1"
A better solution would be to build your own replica of the document panel.